# Is there a way to make Windows Vista command prompt run in 256 colors so I can use my VIM color theme in it?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, vim, colors, command-line

Is there a way to make **Windows Vista command prompt** run in **256 colors** so I can use **VIM** and a 256 color theme in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, the default "command prompt" (aka terminal aka cmd.exe) is not capable of doing what you want.

why aren't you using 'gvim'?

Comment: i will end up using it but i have am having problems opening up files when i load gVim. i type ':e file.html' and it creates a new one when I want it to open up the one in this folder over here. you know? do you know how to open up files in gVim via some built in file search tool? i know about MRU, NERDtree and Fuzzyfinder but right now I cant get them to work! more details on that here http://superuser.com/questions/168751/how-come-all-except-one-of-the-vim-plugins-i-installed-in-windows-vista-vim-do-no

Comment: yes: `:browse e`

Answer (score 3):

There are few terminals which can host console vim and support xterm-256 colors. And of course you need to choose in `.vimrc` proper colorscheme (xterm256 capable). Example:

```
set term=xterm
set t_Co=256
let &t_AB="\e[48;5;%dm"
let &t_AF="\e[38;5;%dm"
syntax on
colorscheme zenburn
```

**mintty**

[image: mintty]

**Poderosa**

[image: Poderosa]

**ConEmu** (I'm the author)

Only official Vim can work properly in ConEmu. cygwin/msys versions can't use 256colors mode because their implementations tries to emulate ANSI processor internally and ANSI sequences do not pass to terminal.

[image: ConEmu]